# Jquery UI Tabs Disable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using jquery UI tabs, i want to disable the tabs. for that i have already setup my tab as describes below for the HTML and the Jquery. The tab control works fine but it doesn't disable the tabs.

```
<div class="tabs-container h-tabs">
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#">tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tab 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div>Tab 1</div>
    <div>Tab 2</div>
    <div>Tab 3</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        $(".tabs-container ul.tabs").tabs("div.tab-content > div", { tabs: 'a', effect: 'fade', fadeOutSpeed: -200, history: false, initialIndex: 1 });


       // DISABLE THE TABS
       $(".tabs-container ul.tabs").tabs("option","disable", [1,2,3]); // IT DOESN'T WORK!!!

    })();
</script>
```

Comment: well, where is the element with class tabs-container in your html?

Comment: @NishadNichoos oh sorry, i have added it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it. Try below code. It should be "disabled" instead of "disable", and the indexes are zero-based:

```
$(".tabs-container ul.tabs").tabs("option","disabled", [0, 1,2]);
```

Comment: Hi @Rajesh. Could you please delete your other answer and in future just make an edit to your original post unless it is a completely different answer! Just clutters up the site a bit :)

Comment: delete the other answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

Im' not sure on your html, replace your html with this

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    Content tab1
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    Content tab2
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    Content tab3
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to disable all your tab, try this code

```
$( ".tabs" ).tabs( "disable" );
```

> **disable()**
>
> Disables all tabs. This method does not accept any arguments.